# How to change the size of plots according to a scale on ggmap?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggmap

I have been trying to plot some data on the map.
With the plot circle of the observed data changing according to a scale.

But the plot produced doesn't reflect the scale.

[See the following.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaDv6.png)

This is the code which I have tried.

```
newmap <- get_map(location = c(lon = 82.5,lat = 24),zoom=4, color="bw")
ggmap(newmap, extent = "normal") +
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour = scale , size = scale), data = final_data)
```

I got the code from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901615/plotting-points-on-a-map-with-size-depending-on-category-count).

My data looks like this.

```
> final_data
        lon       lat  disab scale
1  74.79728 34.083671  27832     1
2  74.87226 31.633979  28119     1
3  75.85728 30.900965  34830     1
4  77.31779 28.408912  33579     1
5  77.10249 28.704059 228427     6
6  75.78727 26.912434  74541     2
7  73.02431 26.238947  24898     1
8  75.86475 25.213816  20843     1
9  77.70641 28.984462  27864     1
10 77.45376 28.669156  84458     2
11 78.00807 27.176670  54382     2
12 80.94617 26.846694  77684     2
13 80.33187 26.449923  81988     2
14 81.84631 25.435801  37750     1
15 82.97391 25.317645  39408     2
16 85.13756 25.594095  68869     2
17 86.95240 23.673945  24627     1
18 88.36390 22.572646 342319     8
19 86.43039 23.795653  28865     1
20 86.20288 22.804566  20766     1
21 85.30956 23.344100  22957     1
22 81.28492 21.190449  22061     1
23 81.62964 21.251384  25868     1
24 78.18283 26.218287  18434     1
25 75.85773 22.719569  56279     2
26 77.41262 23.259933  73219     2
27 79.98641 23.181467  32597     1
28 72.57136 23.022505 188917     5
29 70.80216 22.303894  20219     1
30 73.18122 22.307159  47587     2
31 72.83106 21.170240  55055     2
32 75.34331 19.876165  36205     1
33 79.08815 21.145800  63969     2
34 73.78980 19.997453  26572     1
35 72.83973 19.391928  37382     1
36 72.81771 19.003050 484688    11
37 73.85674 18.520430 127858     3
38 78.48667 17.385044 294072     7
39 80.64802 16.506174  40592     2
40       NA        NA  53865     2
41 77.61586 12.941483 251561     6
42 75.37037 11.874477  33907     1
43 75.78041 11.258753  51981     2
44 76.07400 11.073182  31863     1
45 76.21443 10.527642  38573     2
46 76.26730  9.931233  41432     2
47 76.61414  8.893212  23403     1
48 76.93664  8.524139  39024     2
49 80.27072 13.082680 163428     4
50 78.70467 10.790483  14489     1
51 78.11978  9.925201  19890     1
52 76.95583 11.016844  32794     1
```

It will be ton of help, if someone can help me figure out the problem..:)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because there is no `myscale` column in your data:`final_data`.

Change `myscale` to `scale`:

```
newmap <- get_map(location = c(lon = 82.5,lat = 24),zoom=4, color="bw")
ggmap(newmap, extent = "normal") +
geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour = scale , size = scale), data = final_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Actually I posted an experimenting piece of code.
Even if I change it to scale it is not working.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, new to stackoverflow, I will edit the question.

Comment: More-ever, had I used the variable myscale that way, R wouldn't have plotted data..:)